# Ошибка в приведении типов fromIntegral

Tags: типы, haskell

Только осваиваюсь с языком. Решаю задачки на CodeWars, есть функция:

```
newAvg :: [Double] -> Double -> Maybe Int
newAvg xs navg = Just ( navg * fromIntegral (length xs) )
```

На попытку выполнения получаю ошибку:

```
Codewars/G964/Newaverage.hs:4:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Double'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `navg'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely
      `(navg * (fromIntegral (length xs)))'
```

Не могу понять в чём ошибка. Объясните изъян в логике: При условии что `length []` возвращает тип `Int`, который является подтипом `Integral`, функция `fromIntegral` должна правильно кастовать в `Num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `navg :: Double` и является операндом `*`. У операции `*` оба типа должны быть одинаковыми и совпадать с результатом, поэтому `navg`нужно тоже кастить.

Answer (score 0):

```
 newAvg :: [Double] -> Double -> Maybe Double
 newAvg xs navg = case fromIntegral (length xs) of
     Nothing -> Nothing
     Just l -> Just ( navg * l)
```